# Unable to view mounted volume in Finder

Tags: macos, finder, mount

I am unable to access data on mounted volumes in Finder on OS X Mavericks.

Assuming I mounted a volume by plugging in an external USB disk.

**What works:**

- The volume is listed in the Finder sidebar
- I can access (read+write) it under `/Volumes/MyDeviceName/`
- I see it being listed properly when calling `mount` from the shell

**What doesn't work:**

- I cannot click on it in the Finder sidebar
- When I open `/Volumes` with Finder, `MyDeviceName` is not visible
- When I try to open `/Volumes/MyDeviceName` it says `The folder can't be found.`

This problem doesn't only occur with external USB devices, but also with TrueCrypt Volumes, etc. I thought it might be an NTFS problem, but it also occurs with other file system types.

I've tried to reset the Finder preferences by deleting `com.apple.finder.plist`, as per suggestion by other threads, but this has not solved the issue.

Comment: Try disk Utility and repair permission there for that drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue, which appears to have been a bug or incompatibility with Tuxera NTFS driver (which makes NTFS writable) and Mavericks.

I updated the dependency and it worked. This threw me at first, since I also experienced the issue with non-NTFS volumes. Now however, everything works fine.